# C/C++: calling a function on exit with sigaction() doesn't work

Tags: c++

I've this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <signal.h>

void exfunc(sig_t s) {
    ...
    exit(1);
}

int main(void) {
    ...
    sigaction(SIGINT,exfunc);
    ...
}
```

And when I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:36:25: error: cannot convert 'void (*)(sig_t) {aka void (*)(void (*)(int))}' to 'const sigaction*' for argument '2' to 'int sigaction(int, const sigaction*, sigaction*)'
```

I can't find the mistake. What did I do wrong? I'm new in programming in C/C++.

Comment: This looks like C, not C++.

Comment: From [what I gather](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html), `sigaction` is a structure that you need to populate, not a function pointer type (the `sa_handler` field seems to be where the function pointer goes).

Comment: There's really no such thing as "C/C++". C and C++ are different, and call for different programming styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use signal instead of sigaction. signal is the simplified version of sigaction.

```
signal(SIGINT, exfunc);
```

Using sigaction requires that an array of elements be defined. Useful if you wish to install several signal handlers. A lot of work if you only want one. sigaction also allows access to the many features of signals. signal is simplified and generally does what one would expect.

`exfunc` also has the wrong prototype. sig_t is the typedef for the function proto type:

```
typedef void (*sig_t)(int);
```

This reads, sig_t is a function that takes an int parameters and returns void. Change `exfunc` to

```
void exfunc(int s) {
```

will allow your program to compile.

Comment: It doesn't work either:

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:36:22: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(sig_t) {aka void (*)(void (*)(int))}' to '__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}' [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/signal.h:101:23: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void (* signal(int, __sighandler_t))(int)' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Updated the description with the real problem. :-)

Comment: Hello, Now it seems to work. I have no empty SD-Card at the moment to test the full programm on the Raspberry Pi, but when I delete everything related to wiringPI, it seems to work. THANK YOU!